# How to use recurse method in cypress

Tags: cypress

*I tried this code first time its working fine the second time it failed got error.
cy.eq() failed because this element is detached from the DOM.

...
Cypress requires elements be attached in the DOM to interact with them.
The previous command that ran was:
> cy.get()
This DOM element likely became detached somewhere between the previous and current command.
Common situations why this happens:
- Your JS framework re-rendered asynchronously
- Your app code reacted to an event firing and removed the element
You typically need to re-query for the element or add 'guards' which delay Cypress from running new commands.
All 2 subject validations failed on this subject.*

code:

```
recurse(
          () => cy.get('selectorA').should(Cypress._.noop),
          ($button) => $button.length === 0,
          {
            post() {
              cy.get('selectorA').eq(0).trigger('mouseover', { bubbles: false });
              cy.get('selectorB').eq(0).click({ force: true }).wait(1000);
            },
            delay:1000,
            limit:10,
            timeout:15000
          }
        )
```

Comment: Might be a typo for the example, I see in your `post()` the selector you used is `.selectorA` and not `selectorA`.

Comment: I used dummy selectors here. But I don't know the code working fine for the first time but it not working in the second time got dom element error.